# If GraphQL and Relay are non-negotiable, does it follow that redux is better left out? Or is there not such complete overlap in concerns?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, relay

I've read a lot of heated and contradictory information about this sort of subject and I have no dog in the fight - I have the advantage of an open mind.

Let me walk you through my very informal thought process that led me to think, after using a `boilerplate` with everything in the `relay` kitchen sink, that I still needed something like `redux`.

- In more than a few scenarios, sufficient `redux` boilerplate takes less time and much less thought than the sufficient `GraphQL` and `relay` boilerplate
- The abstraction of `action`s in `redux` is a good thing that keeps many programmers out of trouble by forcing them to separate concerns and to encapsulate the internals of a request / how it works vs the existence of one.
- Specifically, if I am making a canvas editor with lots of tools and brushes, it seems like it would take a long time to get started the right way in `relay` making all those `mutators` and `queries` and so on with care for persistence.
- But if I say, you know, I don't need my app to know every state ever of everything, without something like `redux`, there is no alternative to either managing state via some sort of big container object or winging it, both of which are inferior to `redux`
- Therefore my instinct that `redux` has its place in this scenario is the right instinct

However, I might just not understand how `GraphQL` and `relay` are supposed to be used.

Therefore, I am asking for **concrete answers** about 1) whether this is a fairly objective or subjective question, 2) whether there is a consensus or not, and 3) if I should care.

One more thing - if it is the case that `redux` is fair game in such a scenario, is it still a good rule of thumb that my app ought to have a single store? Or can I start using `redux` more modularly and in mroe of an `adhoc` fashion?

By the way here is a more simple scenario: I want to use a `Stepper` from `material-ui` which requires `State`. Without `redux` my choices are either to faithfully do that at the `relay` level or below, wing it in the components, or try to fudge it somehow or mix it. The only sound option is  the first, and that takes time.